# Highlight Text in RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I am building a windows 8.1 tablet application and I would like to highlight some text in a RichText**Block**.

Does anyone know how to highlight a text in a RichText**Block**. I found the solution for a RichText**Box** but it only works for WPF applications which is not my case.

Otherwise, any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Look at [HighlightBehavior](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Behaviors/HighlightBehavior.cs) from `WinRT XAML Toolkit`. The behavior for `TextBlock`. But I guees you can rewrite it for `RichTextBlock`. You need get all objects with `Text` property. I guess you can start from this logic and organize a new `Blocks` for your `RichTextBlock`

```
foreach (var block in richTextBlock.Blocks)
{
    var paragraph = block as Paragraph;
    if (paragraph != null)
    {
        var runCollection = paragraph.Inlines.Where(x => x is Run).Cast<Run>().ToList();
        foreach (var inline in runCollection)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any examples to use it with a TextBlock? I will try to make it work with a richtextblock.

Comment: @Daniel yes sure, download source code of `WinRT Xaml Toolkit` and look at the sample of highlight  `TextBlock`

Comment: That  HighlightBehavior from WinRT XAML Toolkit simply changes the Foreground color of some word, not the background color. It does not really highlight.